# Document on change isn't working on dynamically changed checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and the issue I am facing is when I call a change method to an input checkbox it invokes and also made the changes to the database, but when I change the select element, it invokes the function but the changes that I made manually to the last checkbox doesn't go away it shows checked but if I inspect the element it doesn't have any checked attribute.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadPackageFeatures();
    })
    $(document).on("change", "input", function () {
        editPackageFeatures()
    })
    $(document).on("change", "select", function () {
        loadPackageFeatures();
    })

    function loadPackageFeatures() {
         var PackageId = "@Model.PackageId";
        let typeid = $("#typeId").find(":selected").val()
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCheckedFeatures","Home")', // Controller/View
                data: { //Passing data
                    Id: PackageId,
                    PkgType: typeid,
                },
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    var CheckedPackageFeaturesIds = data.PackageFeaturesIds
                    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {

                        //this.value always returns a string so have to explicitly converting it into an integer to apply the if statement

                        var currentValue = this.value * 1
                        if (CheckedPackageFeaturesIds.indexOf(currentValue) !== -1) {
                            ($(this).attr('checked', 'checked'))
                        }
                        else {
                            ($(this).removeAttr("checked"))
                        }
                    })
                },
            }
        );
    }

    function editPackageFeatures() {
         var PackageId = "@Model.PackageId";
        let typeid = $("#typeId").find(":selected").val()
        let selectedFeatures = []
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            selectedFeatures.push($(this).val());
        })

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: '@Url.Action("EditPackageFeatures", "Home")', // Controller/View
                data: { //Passing data
                    PackageId: PackageId,
                    PlanType: typeid,
                    PackageFeaturesIds: selectedFeatures
                },
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    
                },
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was with this.attr it was removing the attribute but the state still stays as checked so I just used this.prop and it fixes the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        loadPackageFeatures();
        $(document).on("change", "input", function () {
            editPackageFeatures()
        })
        $(document).on("change", "select", function () {
            loadPackageFeatures();
        })
    })
    

    function loadPackageFeatures() {
         var PackageId = "@Model.PackageId";
        let typeid = $("#typeId").find(":selected").val()
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCheckedFeatures","Home")', // Controller/View
                data: { //Passing data
                    Id: PackageId,
                    PkgType: typeid,
                },
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    var CheckedPackageFeaturesIds = data.PackageFeaturesIds
                    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {

                        //this.value always returns a string so have to explicty converting it into an integer to apply the if statement

                        var currentValue = this.value * 1
                        if (CheckedPackageFeaturesIds.indexOf(currentValue) !== -1) {
                            ($(this).prop('checked', 'checked'))
                        }
                        else {
                            ($(this).prop('checked', false))
                        }
                    })
                },

            }
        );
    }

    function editPackageFeatures() {
         var PackageId = "@Model.PackageId";
        let typeid = $("#typeId").find(":selected").val()
        let selectedFeatures = []
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            selectedFeatures.push($(this).val());
        })
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: '@Url.Action("EditPackageFeatures", "Home")', // Controller/View
                data: { //Passing data
                    PackageId: PackageId,
                    PlanType: typeid,
                    PackageFeaturesIds: selectedFeatures
                },
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    var CheckedPackageFeaturesIds = data.PackageFeaturesIds

                    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                        var currentValue = this.value * 1
                        if (CheckedPackageFeaturesIds.indexOf(currentValue) !== -1) {
                            ($(this).prop('checked', 'checked'))
                        }
                        else {
                            ($(this).prop('checked', false))
                        }
                    })
                },

            }
        );
    }
```